# swift how to develop an app performing an actual bluetooth pair

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

The actual bluetooth pair I am talking about is: let the app shows up in the searching list of Bluetooth of System Settings and other devices can pair to it (like we pair our device to Apple Air Pods).

But all articles I find online are talking about BLE/CoreBluetooth, I don't think these methods could make a device name shows up in the Bluetooth of System Settings.So how to develop an app performing an actual bluetooth pair? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth preferences screen only shows legacy Bluetooth peripherals. Devices advertising BLE services do not appear.

Apps on iOS do not have the ability to create and advertise legacy Bluetooth services.

If you create an app that acts as a BLE peripheral, using Core Bluetooth, and specify that encryption is required for a characteristic then you will trigger a pairing process when an app acting as a Bluetooth central on the other device connects and attempts to read/write that characteristic. Note that this requires cooperating apps on both devices.